# Cocoapods Warning - CocoaPods did not set the base configuration of your project because because your project already has a custom config set

Tags: ios, xcode, cocoapods

After I execute a `pod install` at the base of my project, I get the following error:

> CocoaPods did not set the base configuration of your project because because your project already has a custom config set. In order for CocoaPods integration to work at all, please either set the base configurations of the target `BluePlaquesLondonFramework` to `Pods/Target Support Files/Pods/Pods.debug.xcconfig` or include the `Pods/Target Support Files/Pods/Pods.debug.xcconfig` in your build configuration.

This probably sounds like a silly question, but how do I set the base configuration for a target?

https://github.com/seanoshea/BluePlaquesLondon/blob/ios8/Podfile is the Podfile which is causing this issue.

http://github.com/seanoshea/BluePlaquesLondon on the iOS 8 branch is the Podfile in question if you're curious to see what the project looks like.

Comment: This is a bit off-topic, but; I just want to warn you about iOS-KML-Framework. It uses version 1.5 of TBXML, which is a bit buggy. If you get malformed XML in your feed, your app will crash. You may want to make a private fork for iOS-KML-Framework where you remove the '1.5' from the podspec, and just use the HEAD of TBXML. That seems to fix a lot of the problems.

Comment: https://github.com/CocoaPods/CocoaPods/issues/2633 has a good workaround - set all configs to None, then run "pod install"

Answer (score 679, accepted):

I had the same problem, but in Xcode 6.1.1 - what fixed it for me was to change the configuration file setting to `None` for the two Pods-related targets, then run `pod install` again.

The configuration file setting is found by selecting the project (not the target) and then the Info tab.

Comment: This setting is found by selecting the project (not the target) and then the Info tab.

Comment: It helps to make the change, followed by quitting xcode, running `pod install`, then re-opening. Do not keep Xcode open during that time.

Comment: This fixed it for me. my config was pointing to an old xcconfig name, which changed since I added two explicit targets in my Podfile (one for the main proj one for testing), causing the generation of new config files with different names.

Comment: For those who had the same worry as me that setting that to `None` would break stuff.. the subsequent `pod install` sorts everything out.

Comment: It works, but... Do I have to do this every time I update my pods? I have two a workspace with TWO projects, THREE configurations each (Debug/Release/Distribution) and it's a real PITA to go over all and select "None" for each config file each time Google releases a new version of their maps SDK...

Comment: Oh, it looks like I should run `pod update` instead of `pod install` (source: https://guides.cocoapods.org/using/pod-install-vs-update.html)

Comment: However, if I ever add a new pod to my projects I will have to go over this again...

Comment: where is this setting in xcode 10? Went through all the tabs, couldn't find it

Comment: It works! I would put PROJECT (NOT TARGET) in upper case, I'm developing in Flutter and I have 0 knowledge in iOS dev. Thanks!

Comment: @JenonD , as per your query, for xCode 10, on the right side of the "side menu" in xCode, you'll see "ProjectName" with ^ and \/ symbol (basically a dropdown type menu) click that and you shall find Project and Target section. By default xCode open the project with Target. You have to change it to whatever is inside Project Section.  P.S. This drown-down is in the same line as that of Tabs (General, Resource Tag, Info, Build Settings, etc.).   I hope this helps to the future you or anyone who is looking for the clarity on the same.  Cheers. ;)

Answer (score 363):

## Don't tinker, Reset.

**Step-by-step**

1. Show Project Navigator
2. Select Project
3. Select `Info`
4. In **Configurations**, select each one, one at a time (Debug, ApplicationUnitTest, Release, etc.), and for each target within said configuration, set configuration to **None**.
5. Make certain that *Based on Configuration File* reads **0 Configurations Set** or **No Configurations Set** for **each** configuration. That is the crux.
   [image: 0 Configurations Set]
6. **Quit** Xcode
7. `rm -rf Pods/ Podfile.lock ; pod install`

---

*Once you have allowed `pod install` in step `7` to do its magic, you may be able to use a custom config and change your configurations.*

Comment: Using the `Pods` config, as suggested in other answers, did not resolve my issue in the least bit: **Build Settings** were already matching `Pods.debug` & `Pods.release`, which **was** the problem. What did was **0 Configurations Set** for **each** configuration. Not the same answer whatsoever.

Comment: "[!] Unable to determine Swift version for the following pods:"

Comment: make sure you do the last step in the `ios` folder. Doing it in the root of the project will not have any effect :)

Comment: I have over 50 items in each dropdown for debug, profile and release, do you expect me to manually change each one (150 times) to none ?

Comment: Per @HarshPhoujdar 's concern, I found if you use one hand to click each config, and the other to repeatedly push "N" and "return" keys, you could run through 100+ configs in no time. "N" immediately selects "None".

Answer (score 140):

Go into XCode and open your project settings and under the Info tab, you will see "Configurations" where you can set a configuration file for both Debug and Release. You apparently have already set these to some custom config and CocoaPods wants/needs you to use the Pods config.

[image: Here's a screen shot]

Comment: Note that this doesn't solve the problem if you actually need to use a custom config for a real purpose. See this [open issue](https://github.com/CocoaPods/CocoaPods/issues/2633).

Comment: Nothing has changed in Xcode 6 to make this answer incorrect

Comment: Another issue but it solved my issue for me. Was using cocoa pods with UI Tests and this thing saved my life! Thank you.

Answer (score 71):

Ran into the same problem. It would build on the simulator but not on my device. None of the answers solved this for me. Here's what I did piecing some answers together:

1. Changed my pods file to use a specific target:

   ```
   target :MyProject do
       pod 'AWSCognitoSync'
       pod 'Facebook-iOS-SDK'
   end
   ```
2. Ran pod install
3. That gives an error:
   `` [!] CocoaPods did not set the base configuration of your project because your project already has a custom config set. In order for CocoaPods integration to work at all, please either set the base configurations of the target `MyProject` to `Pods/Target Support Files/Pods-MyProject/Pods-MyProject.debug.xcconfig` or include the `Pods/Target Support Files/Pods-MyProject/Pods-MyProject.debug.xcconfig` in your build configuration. ``
4. Go Project settings and click on Info tab. There will be an error where it cannot find the Configuration file. Set it to "None" for Debug and Release.
5. Run pod install yet again
6. Clean and build. This works.

Comment: Between steps 4 and 5, I always close xcode. I have had issues arise when xcode is running during pod install.

Comment: Just ran into this myself creating custom schemes. The above also works in Xcode 7. I'd recommend @srayhunter advice on closing Xcode during an install.

Comment: I wish I could up vote more than once. This gets me every time.

Answer (score 37):

I fixed my issue after a careful reading of the error message:

> [!] CocoaPods did not set the base configuration of your project
> because your project already has a custom config set. In order for
> CocoaPods integration to work at all, please either set the base
> configurations of the target `Runner` to `Target Support Files/Pods-Runner/Pods-Runner.profile.xcconfig` or include the `Target Support Files/Pods-Runner/Pods-Runner.profile.xcconfig` in your build
> configuration (`Flutter/Release.xcconfig`).

**Solution**

1. Open Xcode and change the Runner Info Base Configurations to the
   related Pods-Runner.profile.xconfig.
2. **Quit Xcode**
3. **Terminal:** From the ios project folder run `pod deintegrate`
4. Verify pods are removed

   ```
   Project has been deintegrated. No traces of CocoaPods left in project.
   Note: The workspace referencing the Pods project still remains.
   ```
5. **Terminal:** From the ios project folder run `pod install`

(from this original - BAD)

[image: bad-image]

(to this GOOD settings)

[image: solution-image]

**Notes**

> I have **not** been able to resolve the issue using the second
> suggestion of including the xconfig file inside of the
> `Flutter/Release.xcconfig` configuration file as mentioned in the
> error message.

Comment: Worked for me. I used the same idea but simpler steps. On the (from this original - BAD) screenshot I set all of them to None. I shut down Xcode and ran pod install. When I opened a project in Xcode again I got (to this GOOD settings) screenshot.

Comment: Once I updated the Runners from "X" to "Pod-Runner.X" the warning of "[!] CocoaPods did not set the base configuration..." went away for me on XCode 14.3 when running $ pod install

Answer (score 33):

For those coming from the Flutter world, this is a misleading error message suggesting an unnecessary action, and the correct course is to ignore the error and use the `flutter` cli (not `pod`), as discussed in https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/73845:

gatzsche says a better message would be:

> In Flutter pod install should not called manually. To run pod install
> execute the following commands `flutter clean`, `flutter pub get` and
> `flutter build ios`.

jmagman notes:

> As you point out, the error message is suggesting an action that isn't necessary. The flutter command suppresses that message from pod. You ran pod directly, which isn't a recommended workflow. We don't have any control of error messages coming from CocoaPods, and the flutter command line tool already suppresses the confusing message.

Answer (score 16):

You should also make sure that you have no pods in the root of `Podfile`, you should define all the pods that are used in many targets like that:

```
def shared_pods
  pod 'ReactiveCocoa', '~> 2.5'
end
target 'app' do
  shared_pods
  pod 'RestKit'
end
target 'tests' do
  shared_pods
  pod 'OCMock'
end
```

You also might need to delete `libPods.a` and `libPods-app.a` from the target dependencies, perform a clean and then run `pod install` again.

Answer (score 10):

I just ran into this issue after adding some custom build configurations. I could see under:

```
Pods (target) > Target Support Files > Pods
```

that it had actually created the new `xcconfig` files that matched the new build configurations but for some reason I could not select these in the project target of my app.

What fixed it for me was to install and use [cocoapods-deintegrate](https://github.com/CocoaPods/cocoapods-deintegrate):

```
gem install cocoapods-deintegrate
```

and then run:

```
pod deintegrate
```

followed by:

```
pod install
```

Comment: This helped me.

Comment: a project is broken.

Answer (score 9):

If you added a custom build configuration to your existing project, Cocoapods will complain about it.

Cocoapods will automatically create xcconfig files under the directory `Pods/Target Support Files/<build_target>` following the naming pattern `Pods-<build_target>.<build_config>.xcconfig`.

Just make sure to manually add those files to your project in Xcode (under the Pods directory, but not inside the Pods project!).  Once those files are included select your project in Xcode, go to the "Info" tab, and expand your custom configuration.  Select the appropriate xcconfig file for each target under your custom configuration.

Answer (score 8):

In case you are using custom config you can follow the suggestion in the warning and include the Pod config in your config file

```
     #include "Pods/Target Support Files/Pods-YYY/Pods-YYYY.develop-archive.xcconfig"
```

This will NOT stop the warnings but will allow you to use your private config (there is an open bug on the warning with CocoaPods project)
https://github.com/CocoaPods/CocoaPods/issues/2633

Comment: Thanks for adding an answer that does not sacrifice your current project setup.

Answer (score 7):

The line in the podfile that is generating a problem is : link_with ['BluePlaquesLondon', 'BluePlaquesLondonFramework'].

Just make  this : link_with ['BluePlaquesLondon'] or this (worked in my case, hope it will in yours :-)) :

```
source 'https://github.com/CocoaPods/Specs.git'
platform :ios, '8.0'

xcodeproj 'BluePlaquesLondon.xcodeproj'
inhibit_all_warnings!
link_with ['BluePlaquesLondon']

def import_pods

     pod 'TTTAttributedLabel', '~> 1.10.1'
     pod 'GoogleAnalytics-iOS-SDK', '~> 3.0.9'
     pod 'Google-Maps-iOS-SDK'
     pod 'IntentKit'
     pod 'HCViews'
     pod 'SVProgressHUD', :head
     pod 'iRate'
     pod 'iOS-KML-Framework', :git => 'https://github.com/FLCLjp/iOS-KML-Framework.git'

end

import_pods

target "BluePlaquesLondonFramework" do
    import_pods
    pod 'Kiwi'
end
```

Comment: This worked beautifully for me. I already had the Cocoapods configurations set as per the accepted answer, but was still seeing the warning. So why does this work, when having `link_with ['BluePlaquesLondon', 'BluePlaquesLondonFramework']` does not?

Answer (score 7):

I had the same error while pod install. I tried everything (reinstall pod, update all gems, etc.) and I found solution worked in my case. There was problem because of changing target's name. In this case solution is simple:

1. Click Product -> Scheme -> Manage Schemes...
2. Click on your target on the list and delete it with "-" sign on bottom of window.
3. Click "+" to add target back to list. Choose correct target and name.

After all everything should works.

Comment: This worked for me, my project is written with Flutter.
Thanks!

Comment: This worked for me too, also with a Flutter project. Thank you!

Answer (score 4):

I moved pods in Podfile outside from the target. File changes from this:

```
# Uncomment this line to define a global platform for your project
# platform :ios, '8.0'
# Uncomment this line if you're using Swift
use_frameworks!

target 'MyProject' do

pod 'Firebase', '>= 2.5.0'
pod 'Onboard'
pod 'GoogleMaps'
pod 'IQDropDownTextField'

end
```

---

To this:

```
# Uncomment this line to define a global platform for your project
# platform :ios, '8.0'
# Uncomment this line if you're using Swift
use_frameworks!

pod 'Firebase', '>= 2.5.0'
pod 'Onboard'
pod 'GoogleMaps'
pod 'IQDropDownTextField'

target 'MyProject' do

end
```

Answer (score 3):

1. Add the relevent xcconfig files to your project. Cocoapods will have created them but you can't set them in Xcode until they are in the project.

   - You probably want to add them to the Pods group where the other pods xcconfig files are. Right click and add files.
   - Search for xcconfig files in your project folder or look in `Pods/Target Support Files/[TARGET_NAME]/` (I have different cocoapods configured for each target (extension and main project this may be slightly different in your case)
2. Go to project configurations in the Info of your main project
3. For each target and configuration set the appropriate pods configuration.
4. `pod install` again and you should see no errors.

Answer (score 3):

This is the messages I got after running pod install or pod update:

```
[!] CocoaPods did not set the base configuration of your project because your project already has a custom config set. In order for CocoaPods integration to work at all, please either set the base configurations of the target `Runner` to `Target Support Files/Pods-Runner/Pods-Runner.debug-staging.xcconfig` or include the `Target Support Files/Pods-Runner/Pods-Runner.debug-staging.xcconfig` in your build configuration (`Flutter/Debug.xcconfig`).

[!] CocoaPods did not set the base configuration of your project because your project already has a custom config set. In order for CocoaPods integration to work at all, please either set the base configurations of the target `Runner` to `Target Support Files/Pods-Runner/Pods-Runner.release-staging.xcconfig` or include the `Target Support Files/Pods-Runner/Pods-Runner.release-staging.xcconfig` in your build configuration (`Flutter/Release.xcconfig`).

[!] CocoaPods did not set the base configuration of your project because your project already has a custom config set. In order for CocoaPods integration to work at all, please either set the base configurations of the target `Runner` to `Target Support Files/Pods-Runner/Pods-Runner.profile-staging.xcconfig` or include the `Target Support Files/Pods-Runner/Pods-Runner.profile-staging.xcconfig` in your build configuration (`Flutter/Release.xcconfig`).
```

This is what I did to solve the issue:

Add Schemes to Podfile under project 'Runner'

```
project 'Runner', {
  'Debug' => :debug,
  'Debug-staging' => :debug,
  'Profile' => :release,
  'Profile-staging' => :release,
  'Release' => :release,
  'Release-staging' => :release,
}
```

Go to ios/Flutter/Debug.xcconfig and include

```
#include "Pods/Target Support Files/Pods-Runner/Pods-Runner.debug-staging.xcconfig"
```

Go to ios/Flutter/Release.xcconfig and include

```
#include "Pods/Target Support Files/Pods-Runner/Pods-Runner.release-staging.xcconfig"
#include "Pods/Target Support Files/Pods-Runner/Pods-Runner.profile-staging.xcconfig"
```

1. flutter clean
2. Delete podfile.lock
3. Pub get
4. pod install

Answer (score 1):

So for me, the problem was due to the aforementioned xcconfig files names being changed before the Swift 3 update took place.

Something was out of sync, so Cocoapods created a 'Recovered References' folder section with the old named files, and linked to them.

To fix this, I:

1. Removed the 'Recovered References' folder and the containing old
   .xcconfig files from Xcode and file system
2. Quit Xcode
3. Run pod install

Everything was handled for me after then, and the warnings were gone.

Answer (score 1):

Just follow the Android Studio instructions.
This is the error output:

```
"[!] CocoaPods did not set the base configuration of your project because your project already has a custom config set. In order for CocoaPods integration to work at all, please either set the base configurations of the target `Runner` to `Target Support Files/Pods-Runner/Pods-Runner.profile.xcconfig` or include the `Target Support Files/Pods-Runner/Pods-Runner.profile.xcconfig` in your build configuration (`Flutter/Release.xcconfig`)."
```

In android studio IDE go to IOS folder/Flutter and open the file Release.xconfig

Then just paste this line:

```
Target Support Files/Pods-Runner/Pods-Runner.profile.xcconfig
```

Delete podfile.lock and try to rebuild in Xcode. Worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to build the project touched by this issue on XCode 6 by:

- selecting Project from the Project Navigator
- choosing Project instead of Target
- going to Info tab
- choosing Pods.(debug/release) Configuration Files from the combobox for the respective Configurations.

Hope this will help someone.

Answer (score 0):

This happened to me because I already had a Pod configuration. I'm new on iOS development, was searching instructions to install Alamofire + SwiftyJSON and ended up installing the libraries more than once, inadvertently. To me, what worked was: on the folder "Target Support Files" in "Pods" project, I selected the two correct .xcconfig files and dragged them to the "Pods" folder of my app project. This enabled the selection of the correct config files on the base configuration.

But then, if I run "pod install" again, the warning will change to the previous .xcconfig file. I try to delete the files and the old framework from the main project but when i ran the previous command once more, gave me the same warning, and created the file "Pods.framework" under the "Pods" folder of my app project. I ignored it, and it seems to be running ok, despite the two frameworks. I don't know if it's right, and a solution, if exists, it would be welcomed.

Comment: This does not really answer the question. If you have a different question, you can ask it by clicking [Ask Question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask). You can also [add a bounty](http://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/set-bounties) to draw more attention to this question once you have enough [reputation](http://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation).

Comment: Thanks for the explanation Petro. I simply wanted to share the result that worked for me (with warnings, but still), yet I will be more careful in the future.

Answer (score 0):

I had error:

```
diff: /../Podfile.lock: No such file or directory diff: /Manifest.lock: No such file or directory error: The sandbox is not in sync with the Podfile.lock.
```

I just checked the path where I was installing the pod and corrected it and installed again,It just worked.

Make sure give the path just before where .xcodeproj or .xcworkspace (if it is already there) exists.

Answer (score 0):

Sorry my previous answer was unclear. This was just one of many errors i've got while trying to set up Cloud Firestore, so this answer is specific for that situation. In order to solve this error and make firebase work, eventually, you have to follow all of the steps from this page: https://firebase.flutter.dev/docs/firestore/overview/ . If you are having problems with generating the 'firebase_options.dart' file, then you need to follow the steps on this page: https://firebase.google.com/docs/cli#mac-linux-auto-script . The last step is optional, but it reduces build time, and I really don't know how or why, but it made some of other errors also disappear... Step 4. Improve iOS & macOS build times, from this page https://firebase.flutter.dev/docs/firestore/overview/. And off course, don't forget to add dependencies in pubspec.yaml: https://pub.dev/packages/firebase_core/install . There is also a great comment here about using Firebase.initializeApp() : https://stackoverflow.com/a/63492262/17626190

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

Seems a good ole system restart and probably more importantly it seems I had to reinstall cocoa pods even though the CLI seemed to be in perfectly working condition and had been working for many days before today.

### Reinstalled CocoaPods

```bash
sudo gem install cocoapods
```

It doesn't seem this was the fix for anyone else, but I figured I should post it since this was driving me nuts, and hopefully it helps at least one other person.

Answer (score -2):

The simplest solution for this (after having this issue multiple times):

1. Delete Podfile & Podfile.lock from your project library (save Podfile somewhere so you could easily paste to new Podfile)
2. run 'pod init'
3. Edit the 'Podfile' to your will (add pods you are using)
4. run 'pod install'

This would recreate everything and works always in minutes (not spending time to reverse engineer the "bug").