# CocoaPods did not set the base configuration of your project because your project already has a custom config set

Tags: xcode, cocoapods, unity-game-engine, vuforia

I am following a tutorial (here is the [link](https://github.com/blitzagency/ios-unity5)) that requires a custom config, and I think that effected my pod file, since I am getting this warning:

> In order for CocoaPods integration to work at all, please either set the base configurations of the target `iBuilt` to `Pods/Target Support Files/Pods-iBuilt/Pods-iBuilt.debug.xcconfig` or include the `Pods/Target Support Files/Pods-iBuilt/Pods-iBuilt.debug.xcconfig` in your build configuration (`iBuilt/Unity.xcconfig`).
>
> [!] CocoaPods did not set the base configuration of your project because your project already has a custom config set. In order for CocoaPods integration to work at all, please either set the base configurations of the target `iBuilt` to `Pods/Target Support Files/Pods-iBuilt/Pods-iBuilt.release.xcconfig` or include the `Pods/Target Support Files/Pods-iBuilt/Pods-iBuilt.release.xcconfig` in your build configuration (`iBuilt/Unity.xcconfig`).

I refered to these links: [StackOverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26287103/cocoapods-warning-cocoapods-did-not-set-the-base-configuration-of-your-project) and [Github](https://github.com/CocoaPods/CocoaPods/issues/2633) for potential solutions, but none of those suggestions worked. So I need your help :)