# flutter: cannot build ios (xcode issues, pod issues?)

Tags: ios, xcode, flutter

### Steps to Reproduce

Simply trying to publish my app to ios store. Already available on Play store. 
I cannot archive in Xcode, constantly running into issues. Currently have these issues when attempting to archive:

[image]

When attempting to run `pod install` in the ios directory, I continue to get this warning (which according to my research seems to be more of an error):

[image]

I tried following everything in [this very long thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26287103/cocoapods-warning-cocoapods-did-not-set-the-base-configuration-of-your-project) thread to resolve this issue, but nothing has worked.

I was able to remove another warning by uncommenting line #2 in the Podfile, `platform :ios, '9.0'`.

I have tried closing Xcode while making changes, and have tried restarting my computer.

I can `flutter run` and the app will work correctly on my iPhone when it is connected to my macbook.

Other threads from which I've tried everything:

- https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/42974
- https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/20685
- https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/48103
- https://github.com/X-Wei/flutter_catalog/issues/26
- https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/28870

**Expected results:**

I can successfully archive in Xcode.

**Actual results:**

Flutter doctor seems to indicate everything is fine, but I continue to get this errors when trying to archive.

```
AdministorsMBP4:mem_plus_plus matt$ flutter doctor --verbose
[✓] Flutter (Channel stable, v1.12.13+hotfix.5, on Mac OS X 10.15.3 19D76, locale en-US)
    • Flutter version 1.12.13+hotfix.5 at /Users/matt/development/flutter
    • Framework revision 27321ebbad (9 weeks ago), 2019-12-10 18:15:01 -0800
    • Engine revision 2994f7e1e6
    • Dart version 2.7.0


[✓] Android toolchain - develop for Android devices (Android SDK version 29.0.1)
    • Android SDK at /Users/matt/Library/Android/sdk
    • Android NDK location not configured (optional; useful for native profiling support)
    • Platform android-29, build-tools 29.0.1
    • Java binary at: /Applications/Android Studio.app/Contents/jre/jdk/Contents/Home/bin/java
    • Java version OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_152-release-1343-b01)
    • All Android licenses accepted.

[✓] Xcode - develop for iOS and macOS (Xcode 11.1)
    • Xcode at /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer
    • Xcode 11.1, Build version 11A1027
    • CocoaPods version 1.8.4

[✓] Android Studio (version 3.4)
    • Android Studio at /Applications/Android Studio.app/Contents
    • Flutter plugin version 37.1.1
    • Dart plugin version 183.6270
    • Java version OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_152-release-1343-b01)

[!] IntelliJ IDEA Community Edition (version 2019.2.4)
    • IntelliJ at /Applications/IntelliJ IDEA CE.app
    ✗ Flutter plugin not installed; this adds Flutter specific functionality.
    ✗ Dart plugin not installed; this adds Dart specific functionality.
    • For information about installing plugins, see
      https://flutter.dev/intellij-setup/#installing-the-plugins

[✓] Connected device (1 available)
    • Takkeezi’s iPhone • {redacted} • ios • iOS 12.4.4
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Try to this.

1. flutter clean
2. pod install
3. build project

Check a pods module

[image]

Pod file

[image]

Comment: I ran `clean flutter` in the base directory, then cd'd to ios directory and ran `pod install`. Then I opened the ios directory in xCode (because when opening the workspace I did not see the `Pods` directory like in your screenshot), and I do not have nearly the folders you do. I'll update the post with the screenshot.

Comment: Your will clearing Cocoapod warning to first. If use to Flutter Profile then check Podfile at down.

project 'Runner', {
  'Debug' => :debug,
  'Profile' => :release,
  'Release' => :release,
}