# Why I get an error in android studio that says CocoaPods not installed even after installing it?

Tags: android-studio, flutter, cocoapods, ios-simulator

I am currently taking a flutter course and everything was going so well until I started running the Clima App code. I am sure the code is correct because I am taking the completed solution from GitHub, but I am getting this error and I am not sure what it is.

Warning: CocoaPods not installed. Skipping pod install.

Could someone please help me figure out this problem? Because I have tried all the possible solutions I found in the internet.

Answer (score 1):

Did you run `pod install` inside the iOS folder?

Comment: I just tried what you suggested and still got an error

Comment: [!] CocoaPods did not set the base configuration of your project because your project already has a custom config set. In order for CocoaPods integration to work at all, please either set the base configurations of the target `Runner` to `Pods/Target Support Files/Pods-Runner/Pods-Runner.profile.xcconfig` or include the `Pods/Target Support Files/Pods-Runner/Pods-Runner.profile.xcconfig` in your build configuration (`Flutter/Release.xcconfig`).

Comment: [!] Automatically assigning platform `iOS` with version `8.0` on target `Runner` because no platform was specified. Please specify a platform for this target in your Podfile. See `https://guides.cocoapods.org/syntax/podfile.html#platform`.

Comment: what do you think I should do?

Comment: please check this out: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26287103/cocoapods-warning-cocoapods-did-not-set-the-base-configuration-of-your-project

Comment: I couldn't understand the solution. I am using android studio and the solution explains it using xcode. Do I need to build the project in xcode?

Comment: Can you try building in xcode and check for errors again?

Comment: I tried to build it in xcode but it didn't work. It looks like xcode doesn't recognize the files. Is there a way to do it by changing some of the preferences in android studio?

Comment: Both of the previous error have disappeared and I was able to successfully execute 'pod install'. But I still get the first error when I try to run the project on ios simulator

Comment: Warning: CocoaPods not installed. Skipping pod install.