# Flutter: fatal error: 'Flutter/Flutter.h' file not found

Tags: flutter, flutter-dependencies

> Xcode's output: ↳
> In file included from /Users/dani/development/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/url_launcher-6.0.3/ios/Classes/FLTURLLauncherPlugin.m:7:
> /Users/dani/development/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/url_launcher-6.0.3/ios/Classes/FLTURLLauncherPlugin.h:5:9:
> fatal error: 'Flutter/Flutter.h' file not found
> #import <Flutter/Flutter.h>
> ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
> 1 error generated.
> In file included from /Users/dani/development/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/shared_preferences-2.0.5/ios/Classes/FLTSharedPreferencesPlugin.m:5:
> /Users/dani/development/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/shared_preferences-2.0.5/ios/Classes/FLTSharedPreferencesPlugin.h:5:9:
> fatal error: 'Flutter/Flutter.h' file not found
> #import <Flutter/Flutter.h>
> ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
> 1 error generated.
> Command CompileSwift failed with a nonzero exit code
> Command CompileSwift failed with a nonzero exit code
> note: Using new build system
> note: Building targets in parallel
> note: Planning build
> note: Constructing build description

flutter doctor:

```
[✓] Flutter (Channel stable, 2.0.5, on macOS 11.2.3 20D91
    darwin-x64, locale en-GB)
[✓] Android toolchain - develop for Android devices (Android
    SDK version 30.0.3)
[✓] Xcode - develop for iOS and macOS
[✓] Chrome - develop for the web
[✓] Android Studio (version 4.1)
[✓] Connected device (3 available)

• No issues found!
```

I tried all solutions proposed here without luck:
https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/16036

All dependencies updated

Comment: Fixed it following these steps: https://stackoverflow.com/a/33509278/4858133.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a matter of finding a library on our app that doesn't support null safety. We can do several things after identify it:

- Ask on its repo to get support for null safety
- Use a different library that supports this
- Try to fix it ourselves

stackoverflow.com/a/33509278/4858133

Answer (score -1):

I believe you should try both of this steps:

1- Try to remove pod files and install them again by executing:

```
$ cd ios/
$ pod deintegrate 
$ pod install
```

2- Clean workplace by executing command on the root of the project:

```
$ flutter clean
```

Then try to run the app again.

Comment: didn't help. In fact it showing more errors now :(

Comment: also the error points to flutter sdk path