# Firebase setup on iOS (Flutter)

Tags: firebase, flutter, firebase-authentication

I'm trying to setup Firebase on iOS in Flutter by following the original guide, but I get the following message after typing `pod install` in the terminal:

```
[!] CocoaPods could not find compatible versions for pod "Firebase/Auth":
  In snapshot (Podfile.lock):
    Firebase/Auth (= 6.34.0, ~> 6.0)

  In Podfile:
    firebase_auth (from `.symlinks/plugins/firebase_auth/ios`) was resolved to 1.4.1, which depends on
      Firebase/Auth (= 8.0.0)


You have either:
 * out-of-date source repos which you can update with `pod repo update` or with `pod install --repo-update`.
 * changed the constraints of dependency `Firebase/Auth` inside your development pod `firebase_auth`.
   You should run `pod update Firebase/Auth` to apply changes you've made.
```

All I changed in the main.dart file is that I changed the default main function to this:

```
    Future main() async {
      WidgetsFlutterBinding.ensureInitialized();
      await Firebase.initializeApp();
      runApp(MyApp());
    }
```

My pubspec.yaml file's relevant part looks like this:

```
    firebase_storage: ^8.0.3
    cloud_firestore: ^1.0.5
    firebase_auth: ^1.1.0
```

I choose these numbers based on a video that used null safety, but tried it with several different ones too like the ones that are mentioned here:
https://firebase.google.com/docs/flutter/setup#analytics-enabled, and also the latest ones, but the error was the same.

I tried reinstalling cocoapods and did the pod repo update, pod setup, pod install multiple times but the output was the same. In the Podfile, I uncommented the ios version number and changed it to 10 as many sources recommended.
I would appreciate your help on this one.

EDIT:
This was my original Podfile:

```
    # Uncomment this line to define a global platform for your project
    platform :ios, '10.0'
    
    # CocoaPods analytics sends network stats synchronously affecting flutter build latency.
    ENV['COCOAPODS_DISABLE_STATS'] = 'true'
    
    project 'Runner', {
      'Debug' => :debug,
      'Profile' => :release,
      'Release' => :release,
    }
    
    def flutter_root
      generated_xcode_build_settings_path = File.expand_path(File.join('..', 'Flutter', 'Generated.xcconfig'), __FILE__)
      unless File.exist?(generated_xcode_build_settings_path)
        raise "#{generated_xcode_build_settings_path} must exist. If you're running pod install manually, make sure flutter pub get is executed first"
      end
    
      File.foreach(generated_xcode_build_settings_path) do |line|
        matches = line.match(/FLUTTER_ROOT\=(.*)/)
        return matches[1].strip if matches
      end
      raise "FLUTTER_ROOT not found in #{generated_xcode_build_settings_path}. Try deleting Generated.xcconfig, then run flutter pub get"
    end
    
    require File.expand_path(File.join('packages', 'flutter_tools', 'bin', 'podhelper'), flutter_root)
    
    flutter_ios_podfile_setup
    
    target 'Runner' do
      use_frameworks!
      use_modular_headers!
    
      flutter_install_all_ios_pods File.dirname(File.realpath(__FILE__))
    end
    
    post_install do |installer|
      installer.pods_project.targets.each do |target|
        flutter_additional_ios_build_settings(target)
      end
    end
```

SOLUTION:
I changed my Podfile to this:

```
    platform :ios, '12.0'
    
    ENV['COCOAPODS_DISABLE_STATS'] = 'true'
    
    project 'Runner', {
      'Debug' => :debug,
      'Profile' => :release,
      'Release' => :release,
    }
    
    def flutter_root
      generated_xcode_build_settings_path = File.expand_path(File.join('..', 'Flutter', 'Generated.xcconfig'), __FILE__)
      unless File.exist?(generated_xcode_build_settings_path)
        raise "#{generated_xcode_build_settings_path} must exist. If you're running pod install manually, make sure flutter pub get is executed first"
      end
    
      File.foreach(generated_xcode_build_settings_path) do |line|
        matches = line.match(/FLUTTER_ROOT\=(.*)/)
        return matches[1].strip if matches
      end
      raise "FLUTTER_ROOT not found in #{generated_xcode_build_settings_path}. Try deleting Generated.xcconfig, then run flutter pub get"
    end
    
    require File.expand_path(File.join('packages', 'flutter_tools', 'bin', 'podhelper'), flutter_root)
    
    flutter_ios_podfile_setup
    
    def flutter_install_ios_plugin_pods(ios_application_path = nil)
      ios_application_path ||= File.dirname(defined_in_file.realpath) if self.respond_to?(:defined_in_file)
      raise 'Could not find iOS application path' unless ios_application_path
    
      symlink_dir = File.expand_path('.symlinks', ios_application_path)
      system('rm', '-rf', symlink_dir) # Avoid the complication of dependencies like FileUtils.
    
      symlink_plugins_dir = File.expand_path('plugins', symlink_dir)
      system('mkdir', '-p', symlink_plugins_dir)
    
      plugins_file = File.join(ios_application_path, '..', '.flutter-plugins-dependencies')
      plugin_pods = flutter_parse_plugins_file(plugins_file)
      plugin_pods.each do |plugin_hash|
        plugin_name = plugin_hash['name']
        plugin_path = plugin_hash['path']
        if (plugin_name && plugin_path)
          symlink = File.join(symlink_plugins_dir, plugin_name)
          File.symlink(plugin_path, symlink)
    
          if plugin_name == 'flutter_ffmpeg'
              pod 'flutter_ffmpeg/full-lts', :path => File.join('.symlinks', 'plugins', plugin_name, 'ios')
          else
              pod plugin_name, :path => File.join('.symlinks', 'plugins', plugin_name, 'ios')
          end
        end
      end
    end
    
    target 'Runner' do
      use_frameworks!
      use_modular_headers!
    
      flutter_install_all_ios_pods File.dirname(File.realpath(__FILE__))
    end
    
    post_install do |installer|
      installer.pods_project.targets.each do |target|
        flutter_additional_ios_build_settings(target)
        target.build_configurations.each do |config|
            config.build_settings['IPHONEOS_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET'] = '10.0'
        end
      end
    end
```

Comment: you're using outdated version of all 3 libraries. Please, check on pub.dev the latest versions in order to make it work correctly and post your "flutter doctor -v" for more details about your setup

Comment: Can you add your Podfile?

Comment: I mentioned that I also tried with those ones too, and got the same result unfortunately.

Comment: I edited the original question there you can see my Podfile.

Comment: Have you tried `pod repo update` & `pod update`?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is my current Podfile setup, you might want to try it:

```
platform :ios, '12.0'

ENV['COCOAPODS_DISABLE_STATS'] = 'true'

project 'Runner', {
  'Debug' => :debug,
  'Profile' => :release,
  'Release' => :release,
}

def flutter_root
  generated_xcode_build_settings_path = File.expand_path(File.join('..', 'Flutter', 'Generated.xcconfig'), __FILE__)
  unless File.exist?(generated_xcode_build_settings_path)
    raise "#{generated_xcode_build_settings_path} must exist. If you're running pod install manually, make sure flutter pub get is executed first"
  end

  File.foreach(generated_xcode_build_settings_path) do |line|
    matches = line.match(/FLUTTER_ROOT\=(.*)/)
    return matches[1].strip if matches
  end
  raise "FLUTTER_ROOT not found in #{generated_xcode_build_settings_path}. Try deleting Generated.xcconfig, then run flutter pub get"
end

require File.expand_path(File.join('packages', 'flutter_tools', 'bin', 'podhelper'), flutter_root)

flutter_ios_podfile_setup

def flutter_install_ios_plugin_pods(ios_application_path = nil)
  ios_application_path ||= File.dirname(defined_in_file.realpath) if self.respond_to?(:defined_in_file)
  raise 'Could not find iOS application path' unless ios_application_path

  symlink_dir = File.expand_path('.symlinks', ios_application_path)
  system('rm', '-rf', symlink_dir) # Avoid the complication of dependencies like FileUtils.

  symlink_plugins_dir = File.expand_path('plugins', symlink_dir)
  system('mkdir', '-p', symlink_plugins_dir)

  plugins_file = File.join(ios_application_path, '..', '.flutter-plugins-dependencies')
  plugin_pods = flutter_parse_plugins_file(plugins_file)
  plugin_pods.each do |plugin_hash|
    plugin_name = plugin_hash['name']
    plugin_path = plugin_hash['path']
    if (plugin_name && plugin_path)
      symlink = File.join(symlink_plugins_dir, plugin_name)
      File.symlink(plugin_path, symlink)

      if plugin_name == 'flutter_ffmpeg'
          pod 'flutter_ffmpeg/full-lts', :path => File.join('.symlinks', 'plugins', plugin_name, 'ios')
      else
          pod plugin_name, :path => File.join('.symlinks', 'plugins', plugin_name, 'ios')
      end
    end
  end
end

target 'Runner' do
  use_frameworks!
  use_modular_headers!

  flutter_install_all_ios_pods File.dirname(File.realpath(__FILE__))
end

post_install do |installer|
  installer.pods_project.targets.each do |target|
    flutter_additional_ios_build_settings(target)
  end
end
```

Comment: I overwritten my Podfile content with this, deleted the podfile.lock file and then ran pod install. The output was the following:
https://pastebin.com/nAXHt2Cm

Comment: I added these lines to your version since it gave me those version errors
{
target.build_configurations.each do |config|
   config.build_settings['IPHONEOS_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET'] = '9.0'
  end}

and got this error in the output:
{
Command PhaseScriptExecution failed with a nonzero exit code}

Comment: This finally solved the problem. I changed my Podfile to the edited one that I am going to put in the original post, and then ran pod repo update and pod update which I am not sure helped me or not. Then it worked after waiting 10 minutes of compiling. Thank you!

Comment: Thanks a lot. I spent about more 2 days to solve that issue and your PodFile solve it.

Answer (score 9):

I had a the same problem solved it simply by changing target to `platform :ios, '14.0'` in Podfile

then in your project `cd ios` to your iOS folder - run :

1. `rm -rf Pods/ Podfile.lock`
2. `pod repo update`
3. `pod install`

**for M1 Mac Users - run this instead :**

1. `rm -rf Pods/ Podfile.lock`
2. `sudo arch -x86_64 gem install ffi`
3. `arch -x86_64 pod repo update`
4. `pod install`

error should be gone

--

*But you might then be left with this last error :*

```
[!] CocoaPods did not set the base configuration of your project because your project already has a custom config set. In order for CocoaPods integration to work at all, please either set the base configurations of the target `Runner` to `Target Support Files/Pods-Runner/Pods-Runner.profile.xcconfig` or include the `Target Support Files/Pods-Runner/Pods-Runner.profile.xcconfig` in your build configuration (`Flutter/Release.xcconfig`).
```

[Set configurations in Xcode as showed in this StackOverFlow Answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33509278/16516595)  to solve it

Comment: I'm using the Mac M1 and this solution worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

Can you try adding those lines at the end of your Podfile:

```
pod 'Firebase/Auth'
pod 'Firebase/Firestore'
pod 'Firebase/Storage'
```

You can check the full list of Firebase pods here: https://firebase.google.com/docs/ios/setup

Alternatively, you can add them like:

```
 pod 'FirebaseFirestore', :git => 'https://github.com/invertase/firestore-ios-sdk-frameworks.git', :tag => '8.0.0'
```

where you can directly link to GitHub repo and version(tag) you want to take, maybe playing around with versions will solve it.

Also, you might try deleting your `Podfile.lock` and then running `pod install`.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem. I fixed it by updating CocoaPods to the newest version (CocoaPods 1.15.0)

```
sudo gem install cocoapods
```