# "LoadError -dlopen..." while pod install in Mac M1

Tags: ios, ruby, flutter, cocoapods, apple-m1

I have Mac M1 and am getting following error while using `pod install` to build flutter project in iOS.
I have already installed home brew, uninstall/install cocoapods using `sudo arch -x86_64 gem install cocoapods`, but still error occurs.
What can I do for solving this probrem..?

```
LoadError - dlopen(/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/ffi-1.15.5/lib/ffi_c.bundle, 0x0009): tried: '/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/ffi-1.15.5/lib/ffi_c.bundle' (mach-o file, but is an incompatible architecture (have 'x86_64', need 'arm64e')), '/usr/lib/ffi_c.bundle' (no such file) - /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/ffi-1.15.5/lib/ffi_c.bundle
/System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.6/usr/lib/ruby/2.6.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:54:in `require'
/System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.6/usr/lib/ruby/2.6.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:54:in `require'
...
```

The result of `flutter doctor -v` has no issues.

```
    [✓] Flutter (Channel stable, 2.10.2, on macOS 12.2.1 21D62 darwin-arm, locale ja-JP)
    • Flutter version 2.10.2 at /Users/sae/development/flutter
    • Upstream repository https://github.com/flutter/flutter.git
    • Framework revision 097d3313d8 (12 days ago), 2022-02-18 19:33:08 -0600
    • Engine revision a83ed0e5e3
    • Dart version 2.16.1
    • DevTools version 2.9.2

[✓] Android toolchain - develop for Android devices (Android SDK version 32.1.0-rc1)
    • Android SDK at /Users/sae/Library/Android/sdk
    • Platform android-32, build-tools 32.1.0-rc1
    • Java binary at: /Applications/Android Studio.app/Contents/jre/Contents/Home/bin/java
    • Java version OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build 11.0.11+0-b60-7772763)
    • All Android licenses accepted.

[✓] Xcode - develop for iOS and macOS (Xcode 13.2.1)
    • Xcode at /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer
    • CocoaPods version 1.11.2

[✓] Chrome - develop for the web
    • Chrome at /Applications/Google Chrome.app/Contents/MacOS/Google Chrome

[✓] Android Studio (version 2021.1)
    • Android Studio at /Applications/Android Studio.app/Contents
    • Flutter plugin can be installed from:
       https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/9212-flutter
    • Dart plugin can be installed from:
       https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/6351-dart
    • Java version OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build 11.0.11+0-b60-7772763)

[✓] Connected device (2 available)
    • iPhone 13 (mobile) • C2EDE2E3-E820-42C2-B0EC-AFC07C401397 • ios            • com.apple.CoreSimulator.SimRuntime.iOS-15-2 (simulator)
    • Chrome (web)       • chrome                               • web-javascript • Google Chrome 98.0.4758.109

[✓] HTTP Host Availability
    • All required HTTP hosts are available

• No issues found!
```

If you need further information, please write a comment.

Answer (score 14):

1. sudo arch -arm64e gem install cocoapods
2. sudo arch -arm64e gem install ffi

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

M1 macs are using ARM proccesors so the

> sudo arch -x86_64 gem install cocoapods

isn't meant for such machines but x86 architectures.
Τry using `sudo arch -arm64e gem install cocoapods`

Comment: Thank you for your comment. I uninstalled cocoapods and used `sudo arch arm64e gem install cocoapods`, but still error exists....

Answer (score 0):

I have no idea why it solved the problem, but pod is updated regularly by using terminal in Mac instead of that in Android studio.
I used terminal of mac, moved the working directory to the ios folder of my project, and did 'pod update'.
It worked for me.

I read the comment of this:[Cannot run the Flutter project with Firebase in MacBook M1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70893361/cannot-run-the-flutter-project-with-firebase-in-macbook-m1)

Comment: if you were trying to install cocoa pods to another folder than ios an error is expected ,because the cocoa pods file exist only in the ios folder

Comment: In terminal of Android, I move the working directory also, but still have the error.( I'm sorry, my English of the post may be confusing)