# Flutter iOS no longer works after adding Firebase

Tags: flutter, firebase

Running the application result into an error.

App is expected to launch on Iphone 13 Simulator

Reproducing output

```
    /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/cocoapods-1.11.3/lib/cocoapods/installer/analyzer.rb:1076:in `resolve_dependencies'
    /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/cocoapods-1.11.3/lib/cocoapods/installer/analyzer.rb:124:in `analyze'
    /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/cocoapods-1.11.3/lib/cocoapods/installer.rb:416:in `analyze'
    /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/cocoapods-1.11.3/lib/cocoapods/installer.rb:241:in `block in resolve_dependencies'
    /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/cocoapods-1.11.3/lib/cocoapods/user_interface.rb:64:in `section'
    /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/cocoapods-1.11.3/lib/cocoapods/installer.rb:240:in `resolve_dependencies'
    /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/cocoapods-1.11.3/lib/cocoapods/installer.rb:161:in `install!'
    /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/cocoapods-1.11.3/lib/cocoapods/command/install.rb:52:in `run'
    /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/claide-1.0.3/lib/claide/command.rb:334:in `run'
    /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/cocoapods-1.11.3/lib/cocoapods/command.rb:52:in `run'
    /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/cocoapods-1.11.3/bin/pod:55:in `<top (required)>'
    /usr/local/bin/pod:23:in `load'
    /usr/local/bin/pod:23:in `<main>'
Error output from CocoaPods:
↳
2
    /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.6/usr/lib/ruby/2.6.0/universal-darwin21/rbconfig.rb:230: warning: Insecure world writable dir /usr/local/bin in PATH, mode 040777
    [!] Automatically assigning platform `iOS` with version `10.0` on target `Runner` because no platform was specified. Please specify a platform for this target in your Podfile. See `https://guides.cocoapods.org/syntax/podfile.html#platform`.
Error running pod install
Error launching application on iPhone 13.
Exited
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think so, the problem is you have not specified the version of iOS in your podfile.

So, please specify the version as below in your podfile.

```
platform :ios, '11.0'
```

Comment: Yes, awesome. Thank you for this response

Answer (score 1):

After trying out a couple of suggestions, I finally got the solution
The doc link was helpful https://firebase.flutter.dev/docs/migration#cocoapods-could-not-find-compatible-versions-for-pod

uncomment this line, if commented `platform: 9` then change to `platform: 11`

1. delete podfile.lock
2. cd ios/
3. pod install --repo-update (recommended)

*that's it.*

Just in case you get this warning

CocoaPods did not set the base configuration of your project because your project already has a custom config set. In order for CocoaPods integration to work at all, please either set the base configurations of the target `Runner` to `Target Support Files/Pods-Runner/Pods-Runner.debug.xcconfig` or include the `Target Support Files/Pods-Runner/Pods-Runner.debug.xcconfig` in your build configuration (`Flutter/Release.xcconfig`).

I recommend checking out this link [Cocoapods Warning - CocoaPods did not set the base configuration of your project because because your project already has a custom config set](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26287103/cocoapods-warning-cocoapods-did-not-set-the-base-configuration-of-your-project)