Cocoapods error when using cloud_firestore
Stack overflow mentioned I previously posted low quality questions so here is my attempt at a high quality question...
I get an when running flutter run. It seems odd because it only happense after adding cloud_firestore: ^4.17.3 to the dependecies. This is the error:
Error: CocoaPods's specs repository is too out-of-date to satisfy dependencies.
To update the CocoaPods specs, run:
  pod repo update



Error running pod install
Error launching application on iPhone 14.

For reference, here are my dependencies:
dependencies:
  flutter:
    sdk: flutter
  cupertino_icons: ^1.0.6
  flutter_osm_plugin: ^1.0.3
  intro_slider: ^4.2.1
  salomon_bottom_bar: ^3.3.2
  csv: ^5.0.0
  ml_dataframe: ^1.6.0
  latlong2: ^0.9.1
  flutter_map: ^6.1.0
  firebase_core: ^2.30.1
  firebase_auth: ^4.19.4
  cloud_firestore: ^4.17.3

What have I tried so far?

pod repo update
uninstalling and reinstalling cocoapods
cd ios followed by pod install. This returns the following error (for which I have also tried its suggestions):

[!] CocoaPods could not find compatible versions for pod "Firebase/CoreOnly":
  In snapshot (Podfile.lock):
    Firebase/CoreOnly (= 10.24.0)

  In Podfile:
    firebase_core (from `.symlinks/plugins/firebase_core/ios`) was resolved to 2.31.0, which depends on
      Firebase/CoreOnly (= 10.25.0)


You have either:
 * out-of-date source repos which you can update with `pod repo update` or with `pod install --repo-update`.
 * changed the constraints of dependency `Firebase/CoreOnly` inside your development pod `firebase_core`.
   You should run `pod update Firebase/CoreOnly` to apply changes you've made.

Running Firebase/CoreOnly returned:
Pod installation complete! There are 7 dependencies from the Podfile and 30 total pods installed.

[!] CocoaPods did not set the base configuration of your project because your project already has a custom config set. In order for CocoaPods integration to work at all, please either set the base configurations of the target `Runner` to `Target Support Files/Pods-Runner/Pods-Runner.profile.xcconfig` or include the `Target Support Files/Pods-Runner/Pods-Runner.profile.xcconfig` in your build configuration (`Flutter/Release.xcconfig`).


I followed these instructions - no success. I then tried starting a new project (therefore it shouldn't have custom build configurations), adding cloudfirestore and firebase_auth to the dependencies and I have the same problem.

These steps worked for me:
flutter clean

Remove /ios/Pods

Remove /ios/Podfile.lock

flutter pub get

from inside ios folder: pod install

flutter run


This gives me the cocoapods did not install the base configuration... error again

Take a look at this:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26287103/cocoapods-warning-cocoapods-did-not-set-the-base-configuration-of-your-project

Software update solved this issue - especially strange because when I first encountered the problem, I was on the most up to date version.
